# How to declare enumerator values inside a macro?

Tags: c++, enums, macros, components, factory-pattern

Preamble: This question is relatively high-level, do not feel any pressure to answer to the question directly. For example, if you believe in a better design approach, please let me know.

## Why we need this:

We are making a software that should be easily modifiable, use ECS design pattern and follow Open-Closed principle. This creates the following requirements:

1. Objects hold a FeatureList, which is a bitfield where each bit represents a Component, as per common Entity-Component Systems.
2. When coding new Features, there is no need to #include them anywhere in the program. This should make it more user-friendly to code in and more modifiable.
3. Features should not have hard-coded values. This should make it quick to disable, change and reformat features.

And this can all be done: [Minimal reproducible example](https://onlinegdb.com/5pPAraA0d) and a [simplified UML diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcSch.png)

And as you can test out yourselves the code works.

## Issue:

However, we have a a big design issue: <sub>(Not the crash if we go higher than second bit, this was a minimal example)</sub>

```cpp
ExampleObject->FeatureList |= (1 << 0); // Spawn Feature1
ExampleObject->FeatureList |= (1 << 1); // Spawn Feature2
ExampleObject->FeatureList |= (1 << 2); // Spawn Feature3
```

As you can see, we have hard-coded feature values. This breaks our third requirement. These hard-coded values are also based on compile order, which isn't ideal.

This can be  fixed with a search algorithm to find integers from `std::unordered_map<int, std::string> Map;`. Example code would look like this:

```cpp
ExampleObject->FeatureList |= (1 << FeatureRegistry::GetInstance().GetFeatureValue("Feature1"));
ExampleObject->FeatureList |= (1 << FeatureRegistry::GetInstance().GetFeatureValue("Feature2"));
ExampleObject->FeatureList |= (1 << FeatureRegistry::GetInstance().GetFeatureValue("Feature3"));
```

But this requires usage of hard-coded strings: If a Feature's name were to change or be completely removed, there would be no quick way to replace this name across the codebase or disable Feature spawning. <sub>(We'd have to rely on compiler errors, which isn't ideal)</sub>

There is one solution that handles Names-to-Integers without hardcoding the values: Enumerators. We can even use autocompletion on most IDEs to make it clear what we can and cannot spawn, as well as replace names and set values to null easily!

**So we'd need an enumerator which has a defined value for each registered Feature.**

This is very simple: Add an enumerator into `REGISTER_FEATURE` macro, and… There isn't a clear way forward here. There is no information of dynamically allocating enumerators or declaring enumerators inside macros shared between between multiple files: There are opaque and anonymous enumerator declarations, but it is not clear how these can be utilized.

## Final question:

How to declare enumerator values inside a macro?

Comment: Avoid using macros in modern C++. They usually cause more trouble than they solve in the long run and except for *very rare* cases there are always better alternatives.

Comment: For example have a look at [function templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template). The only reason I can still think of to use macros is if you have to concatenate characters but that should be very rare.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to why you are using a macro?

Comment: @Amolgorithm The preprocessor operator # is used to avoid hard-coding values, as per requirement #2. The macro allows changing the centralized registry without modifying Factory.h code. If you believe there is a better way to do this, do tell.

Comment: If I understand correctly, isn’t this immediately impossible because of separate translation?  You can’t have multiple translation units conspire to create unique integers at compile time.

Comment: I seriously considered writing a macro to generate code in a cross-platform repository given a function declaration, and quickly realized it was going to be a maintenance nightmare so I threw that idea out of the window. Is there a reason you can't simply define the enum value itself manually, as opposed to having a macro do it for you? It wouldn't have a _hardcoded_ value, since the compiler defines the value of each enum entry unless it's explicitly specified - so, adding a new entry anywhere would bear no functional difference.

Comment: If you are not happy to refer to the feature as `"Feature1"`, why would you be happy to refer to it as `EnumeratorNamedFeature1`? What's the difference? If `Feature1` is renamed, you'd have to search and replace either way.

Comment: Anyway, `EnumeratorNamedFeature1` could be, say, a global variable of a class with `operator int()` that returns `FeatureRegistry::GetInstance().GetFeatureValue("Feature1")`. Or, come to think of it, could just be a `static int` variable initialized to ``FeatureRegistry::GetInstance().GetFeatureValue("Feature1")``; within `REGISTER_FEATURE` macro, the index for the just-registered feature is already known.

Comment: How about an `awk` or `perl` script to generate whatever C++ source you deem necessary from some master 'steering file'.  This file can then be in a format of your own devising and you can make the script do whatever you want.  You can probably even get your build system to re-run the script if the steering file changes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You cannot "search and replace" a string. I mean, you can, but you get a lot of false positives you must manually check out. The integer values are based on file order, so hardcoding them isn't a great idea. Enum would simplify everything here. Also it would autocomplete.

Comment: @PaulSanders As long as we don't need to manually change this "steering file" when adding new features, this would work

Comment: Well, I don't think you can generate an enum, but it should be easy for `REGISTER_FEATURE` to generate a named const int variable with the right value.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Wouldn't that variable be only usable with an #include of the Feature? Because we are trying to avoid this.

Comment: Well, for a symbolic name to become available, the source file has to include *something* that declares it. Let's try it this way: in the ideal world where you have a magic wand that can arrange sources and headers exactly the way you want it, what would `main.cpp` in your example look like? Note that this magic wand can't change how the compiler works, only how its inputs are arranged; a name still has to be declared before it can be used.